# Dynamic color in items in ddl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, colors, combobox

```
  SelectedValuePath="Id"
               Width="200" Foreground="{Binding Path=TextColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConv}}"/>
```

textColor is hexCode in string.

I want to set foreground of eeach item in combBox which depend on TextColor.
But myConverter hasn't called.

Why?

Comment: Please show us your converter.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom((string)value));  
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```